# django: How can I create a custom Logging Filter for SuspiciousOperation exception?

Tags: django, logging

After migrate to 1.11 ( from 1.8 ) I'm receiving some `SuspiciousOperation` errors from logging.

It seems it comes from JS request who keeps session alive if user move their mouse. But this is not important.

How can I filter just this exception?

**What I tried:**

I just created a filter somewhere:

```
import logging

from django.core.exceptions import SuspiciousOperation

class StopSuspiciousOperation(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        if record.exc_info:
            exc_value = record.exc_info[1]
            return isinstance(exc_value, SuspiciousOperation)
        return True
```

Then I added this filter to my configuration:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
        },
        'stop_suspicious_operation': {
            '()': 'aula.utils.loggingFilters.StopSuspiciousOperation',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false',
                        'stop_suspicious_operation',], #<-- here
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

But I'm still receiving the error:

Internal Server Error: /keepalive

```
SuspiciousOperation at /keepalive
The request's session was deleted before the request completed. The user may have logged out in a concurrent request, for example.

Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://XXXXXX/YYYYYY
Django Version: 1.11.9
Python Executable: /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the correct answer, but I think django is catching the SuspiciousOperation at WSGI level and is logging an ERROR. See:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#suspiciousoperation

> If a SuspiciousOperation exception reaches the WSGI handler level it
>   is logged at the Error level and results in a HttpResponseBadRequest.

You maybe just want to filter out the bad requests like this:

```
from logging import LogRecord


def filter_400(record: LogRecord) -> bool:
    '''Filter out HTTP Error Code 400 Bad Request'''
    return record.status_code != 400
```

Comment: yeah, that would be smart *blush* I'll edit the answer.

Comment: any case, your flter is for all 400 ops. See my answer ( I undeleted it temporarily just to show it to you ) that does not work

Comment: That is correct. It filters *all* Bad Request logs, which is eventually not the desired behavior. But your answer does not work. One could also filter by this criterion: record.name != 'django.security.SuspiciousOperation'

Comment: I know my answer don't works, because this I deleted it :)