# How to prevent admin emails for SuspiciousOperation errors

Tags: django, session

My Django application throws a lot of SuspiciousOperation error, for which the admins receive an email:

```
SuspiciousOperation at /api/rest-auth/logout/
The request's session was deleted before the request completed. 
The user may have logged out in a concurrent request, for example.
```

There is nothing suspicious about this. It started happening when we introduced a auto logout timeout functionality, so now when multiple requests come in from the same user, and the auto logout timeout is reached, this error happens. Not always, but quite frequently.

Is there a way of preventing this error, or at least preventing the email.

I found that the code that generates the error comes from `process_response` in the `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware`, so I was thinking of overriding the the whole middleware class, and removing the line that produces the error, but it seems like an overkill.

Comment: I think you should be able to filter it out with your `LOGGING` configuration. There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287987/) about this, but nobody answered with a configuration that would work.